# Linking offline documentation to IDLE - Linux

Tags: python, python-idle

With internet access, < F1 > on IDLE works fine on Linux.  With no internet access of course it does not work.  I have downloaded the Python doc as html, but can't get IDLE to refer to it directly.

There is a dialog under "IDLE Preferences" called "Additional Help Sources", but this only enables the user to specify single files for single subjects, not the whole directory structure.  I can enter a URL, but I am unclear as to what I should enter as the "Menu Item".

I should add that adding the URL to the local directory to my browser enables me to look at the offline doc, it is just the link to IDLE I am missing.

I found reference to a PYTHONDOCS environment variable, but this does not appear to work on Linux, it seems it is specific to Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost did all settings you need to refer to local documentation via menu item. Let's look more precisely of what can be done:

1. Download documentaion for your Python version as [zipped html](http://docs.python.org/ftp/python/doc/2.7.3/python-2.7.3-docs-html.zip).
2. Unpack that archive to you desired directory, e.g */home/username/python-docs*.
3. Go to Idle: Options -> Configure Idle... -> General -> Additional help sources -> Add.
4. Enter label for the "Menu item" field (it will be a label of a new menu item that will appear in IDLE's Help menu), e.g. "local docs".
5. Press "Browse" button and choose path to "index.html" in unzipped help sources.
6. Move to Help -> local docs, it will open your local version of Python documentation.

**UPDATE:**

I've created a [ticket](http://bugs.python.org/issue15808) on Python issue tracker that requests enhancement of standard IDLE keys configuration so it could be possible to add key bindings for custom added addiotional help sources menu items.

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks.  I had misunderstood the effect of entering the Menu item.  However, it still does not reassign the < F1 > key.  Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @cdarke As far as I know it's only possible to redefine hotkeys for predefined actions Options -> Configure Idle... -> Keys, and for now it's not possible to define custom hotkeys for "additional help sources" menu items. You can post "enhancement" issue to Python issue tracker with this request.

Comment: Fair enough, it is only reasonable to gild the lilly so far.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, IDLE does have code to look for an on-disk copy of the html-formatted Python documentation set but the paths are platform-specific and, in the Linux case, are out-of-date for some distributions at least.  If you look at the code in [`Lib/idlelib/EditorWindow.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/idlelib/EditorWindow.py) (I'm looking at the current Python 3 sources), you'll see that for Linux platforms it looks for `index.html` in either `/var/www/html/python` or `/usr/share/doc/python-docs-x.y/Doc/`.  On current Debian systems, for example, the Python doc package is installed in `/usr/share/doc/pythonx.y-doc/html`.  If you install the doc packages and then create a link, IDLE should find the docs off-line when you select `Python Docs` from the `Help` manual.  For example, for Python 3.3 you *could* do:

```
sudo aptitude install python3.3-doc
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html/
sudo ln -s /usr/share/doc/python3.3-doc/html python
```

That said, the default locations should be updated (I'll add this to the issue that Rostyslav opened).

Comment: Thanks, I sucessfully copied the doc to /var/www/html/python on CentOS (I have root access).  Obviously using this path is not a good solution with > 1 Python version (I'm on 3.2.3).  I'm a little surprised that the paths can't be manipulated by an environment variable (like PYTHONDOCS on Windows).